# Ruby String to Time conversion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In ruby on rails, how can I convert `string` (e.g. "06:00 AM") to `Time` ("06:00 AM").

I am trying to get the time `3hrs` after the given time. The problem is that, the field I am using to hold the `time` is in `string`. With my understanding, we cannot evaluate `string` or can we? I just want a time `3hrs` after the given time, but without converting the `string` field to `Time` field, it seems not possible.

I can get the time `(06:00 AM)` in `Time` format with `strftime("%I:%M %p")`, but this is not my scenario. I just want to convert the `string` into the `time` format.

Please can someone help with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do call [`to_time`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-to_time) method.

```
"06:00 AM".to_time
# => 2015-05-27 06:00:00 +0530
```

Comment: Great, But how can I get `2.hours.ago` (suppose) with that time

Comment: @SujitS See this method... http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_ago_in_words .. Just do `time_ago_in_words("06:00 AM".to_time -  2.hours)`..

Answer (score 1):

Using `to_time` with older version of Rails might give:

> ArgumentError: invalid date

In such case you can use:

```
Time.parse("06:00 AM")
# => 2015-05-27 06:00:00 +0530
```

Comment: Great, But how can I get 2.hours.ago (suppose) with that time

Comment: @SujitS arup has already answered that correctly, so im not updating it here. :)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I cannot accept both answer as correct. :)